# Create java installer from a Tomcat project (war)

Tags: java, tomcat, installation, war

I want to create an installer from a Tomcat project. The tasks that have to do this installer is to ask the user several input parameters, which are then updated in a properties file, within the war file. After this, the installer will copy the war file to TOMCAT_HOME webapps folder with the updated properties file, which contains parameters that user entered.
I tested several software like IzPack or Antigen, but I find none that can do what I ask. Do you know how can I do what i want?
Regards and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy to do this with a simple Swing application.

WAR archives are simple ZIP archives with a special layout, so all you need is to open the file and overwrite (or add) the updated properties.

Unfortunately, [the `ZipFile` API doesn't allow to modify an existing ZIP archive](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4129445) ([bug 4129445](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4129445), open for more than 10 years at the time of writing), so you will need [the truezip library](http://truezip.java.net/).

That said, we prefer not to modify the WAR archives in any way. Usually a much better solution is to define a property (like `com.pany.app.configPath`) which gives you the path of the config file. This way, all users get the same WAR and the property file is external.